# How to get Preferences in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I don't understand how preferences work.

I have a preferences activity and one field on it:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:key = "@string/pr_rest_service_url"
    android:title = "@string/rest_service_url"
    android:summary = "%s"
    android:shouldDisableView="false"
    android:selectable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:defaultValue="543543543"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In preference activity i use this code to edit it:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    String editTextPrefKey = getString(R.string.pr_rest_service_url);
    EditTextPreference restUrlTExtEdit = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(editTextPrefKey);
    restUrlTExtEdit.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    restUrlTExtEdit.setSummary(restUrlTExtEdit.getText());

    restUrlTExtEdit.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });

    Preference saveButton = findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_save_button));
    saveButton.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

And its works. Works nice.
Now i want to get preferense from another parts of application. I put this code in MainActivity:

```
String key = this.getString(R.string.pr_rest_service_url);
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String g = mSharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
```

And got `null`.
So how gonna work with preferences?
Or i made mistake on ths start and should not use `PreferenceActivity` as settings screen? Or preferenses binded to activity?
So how can i get

*UPDATE*

I tried

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String name = sp.getString("myKey", "");
```

But got empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Use this then:

```
SharedPreferences yourOutputdata =
context.getSharedPreferences("YourKEY", MODE_PRIVATE); // Save as YourKEY in the Activity which you're passing data to this one ...
```

---

Because of this:

```
String key = this.getString(R.string.pr_rest_service_url);
```

You are actually getting string from resource file and saving it to preference which I believe this causes the null.

**Try this:**

To save:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key","your text-data here");
editor.apply();
```

And to get:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = sp.getString("key", "");
```

Comment: This don't helps. `name` is empty string. Im already mad with it. Couse on my phone `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` works, on friend of mine's phone this don't work. On Android Emilator this don't work.

Comment: I've actually explained why it returns null. Also, you didn't save anything to get by `SharedPreference` instead, you were trying to get a resource string which was returning null.  However, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get Android Shared Preferences from default shared preferences in java language:-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPreferences.getString("your_key", null);
```

Hope this works...

Comment: This answer is clearer than the other one by ʍѳђઽ૯ท.  It works and solved my problem perfectly.  The OP was asking how to get saved preferences, not how to save them or anything else.  Don't understand why I'm the only one upvoting it.